# RedBeanPHP, R::dispense(); не работает

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование, redbeanphp

Изучаю PHP и RedBeanPHP. При работе с ним не работает dispense и выдает ошибку:

`Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to RedBeanPHP\Util\DispenseHelper::dispense() must be an instance of RedBeanPHP\OODB, null given, called in C:\MAMP\htdocs\rb.php on line 13600 and defined in C:\MAMP\htdocs\rb.php:16784 Stack trace: #0 C:\MAMP\htdocs\rb.php(13600): RedBeanPHP\Util\DispenseHelper::dispense(NULL, 'users', 1, false) #1 C:\MAMP\htdocs\check.php(18): RedBeanPHP\Facade::dispense('users') #2 {main} thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\rb.php on line 16784`

Код:

```
<?php

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

require 'rb.php';

try
{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1:8889;dbname=users','root','root');

} catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getmessage();
}

$table = R::dispense('users');
$table->text = 'Hello World';
$table->test = 'This is test';

R::store($table);
?>
```

Много было постов с такой же ошибкой, связанной с проблемой названия таблицы (без спец. символов, верхних регистров и тд, тп). Но в моем случае, я все делал по документации. Буду благодарен, если поможете и заранее спасибо!

Comment: я порекомендую убрать из этого кода всякое упоминание о redbean, прописать нормальное соединение с PDO, и работать с БД через нормальную библиотеку, а не это недоразумение

Comment: О да, спасибо! Сам увидел, так устал и даже не заметил. Спасибо вам огромное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный вариант без PDO `<?php

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

require 'rb.php';

R::setup( 'mysql:host=localhost:8889;dbname=root', 'root', 'root' );
if(!R::testConnection()) die('No DB connection!');

$table = R::dispense('users');
$table->text = 'Hello World';
$table->test = 'This is test';

R::store($table);
```

?>`

Comment: вообще-то я писал всё наоборот. выкинуть r и оставить PDO. Так вы сэкономите себе очень много времени и нервов.

Comment: Ну, я оставлю это для тех, кто будет его использовать